# Restangular Requests not showing in (Chrome) Network Tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, restangular

When using Restangular with the following configuration, I can't see the requests inside the "Network" tab of any browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox). 
Using $http directly works fine though.

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
   RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api/v1');
});
```

On the demo site however (http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview), all requests are showing up.

How is it even possible for a request not to show up in the DevTools Network tab? Is there a Restangular configuration for it that I did not find?

Any help on this would be very appreciated :)

Comment: check that you did not select wrong request type filter

Comment: Thanks for the idea :) Already checked that, filter is set on "All" and I do see other resources like images, scripts and $http requests. Only the Restangular requests are missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We figured it out eventually. There was a middleware that sent out the requests via a socket connection. That's why they didn't show up in the network tab. So it had nothing to do with Restangular. 
But thanks for your suggestions!

Edit: You can even see the messages that are being sent via the socket connection in the network tab by choosing the "WS" filter, clicking on the initial request and then opening the "messages" tab

Answer (score 0):

Try Restangular services, they are awesome:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('someModule')
        .factory('YourRestangular', ['Restangular', YourRestangular]);

    function YourRestangular(Restangular) {
        return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
            RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('/api/v1');
        });
    }
}());
```

And then:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('someModule')
        .factory('Users', function(YourRestangular) {
            return YourRestangular.service('users');
        });}());
```

Comment: Thanks, that is cool indeed. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem of the requests not showing up in the network tab :/